# Bash script: Tar not working properly

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I've just put together the below shown bash script in order to make continuous backups from a set folder.

It appears however that the `find` call seems to not only include `/home/myfoldertobackup/` in the backup, but also the tar it checks file age of. Why on  earth is this and what can I do to only make sure that the previously mentioned folder only is put into the tar?

```
if [ -e $filename ];
then
    # Tar exist. Check if tar is older than five days and if so, update it.
    find $filename -mtime +5 -exec tar -czvf $filename /home/myfoldertobackup/ {} \;
else
    #Tar doesn't exist. Force creation of tar!
    tar -czvPf $filename /home/myfoldertobackup/
fi
```

Comment: Note that your backup strategy ensures that if the new backup fails for any reason, your previous backup has been destroyed - so you are worse off than you were before.  Do not destroy the old backup until you know that the new one is complete.

Comment: Hi Jonathan. Absolutely good point! Would you say that making the tars in an temp location and then moving them in to the backup target place would be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "$filename" last modification time is older than 5 days, find runs the following command:

```
tar -cvfz $filename /home/myfoldertobackups/ $filename
```

which puts /home/myfoldertobackup **and** $filename (probably truncated since tar is going to write on it) in $filename; if you don't want $filename just write

```
find $filename -mtime +5 -exec tar -cvz /home/myfoldertobackups -f {} \;
```

or better (because more readable)

```
if [ -n "$(find $filename -mtime +5)" ]; then
    tar -cvzf "$filename" /home/myfoldertobackups;
fi
```

*UPDATE*

Here is your code with my proposed change:

```
if [ -e $filename ];
then
    # Tar exist. Check if tar is older than five days and if so, update it.
    # find $filename -mtime +5 -exec tar -czvf $filename /home/myfoldertobackup/ {} \;
    if [ -n "$(find $filename -mtime +5)" ]; then
        tar -cvzf "$filename" /home/myfoldertobackups;
    fi
else
    #Tar doesn't exist. Force creation of tar!
    tar -czvPf $filename /home/myfoldertobackup/
fi
```

Comment: Hi Marco! Big thanks for this. I might be slightly retarded, but does your solution take account the fact that the file might not exist also?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with you: my solution replaces only the find command; anyway, I'll update my answer with the full code :)

Answer (score 2):

that is because `find` replaces `{}` for the name of the file it found.
Just drop `{}` and you are done.